# How to get non-striped table in AsciiDoctor?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I have this table:

```
[width="10%", cols="^", options="header"]
|===
| header
| one
| two
| three
| four
|===
```

Which renders as:

[image: striped]

In order to get to none-striped:

[image]

I do this:

```
[width="10%", cols="^", options="header"]
|===
| Header
| one
{set:cellbgcolor:white}| two
| three
| four
|===
{set:cellbgcolor!}
```

But the disadvantage of this is clear (verbosity, forcing specific color, ...), not to state that it doesn't work in other AsciiDoctor variants (e.g. PDF)

I am aware of [issue #1365](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1365), but it's very new, and only implemented in the ruby variant of AsciiDoctor, not in its JS variant (with which most of the WYSIWYG editors work).

Long story short - is there anyway to achieve it in present state?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try 'stripes=none' ([manual](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#striping))?

```
[cols="2,4,2,4,2", stripes=none, grid=none, frame=none]
|===
| ^.>| +++_____________________+++ | ^.>| +++_____________________+++ |
| ^.<| Unterschrift                | ^.<| Unterschrift                |
|===
```